# Add Tag in YouTrack workflow with applyCommand()

Tags: workflow, youtrack

In Jetbrains YouTrack, there is own made (HelpDesk) workflow it work fine. When a new email come in it make an Issue and check the Riporter's email (reporterEmail). It add a tag to the Issue by the reporterEmail.

I used first Issue.addTag method, [reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/v1-Issue.html#addTag). It works when any of 'Support Admin' change anything in the Issue. (The tag is added). But it is not added at the first come in.

After a few hour research I found the problem (I don't receive any errro in console).  There is no permission to the Tags and I can not grant permission to the riporters (because it is a special group).
In next solution: I went over to Issue.applyCommand method. [reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/v1-Issue.html#applyCommand)

Firstly some problems with the user (main-user entity). After a few try, it seems work. No error message. But the Tag is not added. I think i my command `add tag {testg}` is wrong what is would to apply:

```
if (reporterEmail.includes("test@mail.com")) {
      console.log('testRun'); //it is shown at the console
      issue.applyCommand("add tag {testg}", mainUser);
      isTag = true;
    }
```

`add tag {testg}` It works in normal command window (on server public gui), but not in the workflow script.